# Does my hanging light have to Match other lighting in the house?

Tags: lighting

we recently moved into a new house and all the lighting is brushed nickel which is okay but we cannot afford to replace them all. In the livingroom I would like to put a large chandelier in the vaulted ceiling. However, this opens to the kitchen and dining rooms. Can I pick an entirely different finish for this hanging light?  I love the wrought iron look but with the hanging kitchen light, would this look bad?  I looked at brushed nickel or silver lights and they are just too formal or I do not like them. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: A few things you can do to tie it together. 1) Stick with the same color family (black/grey). Black goes better with nickle/silver than something in the brown/yellow family, like brass/bronze, if you're adding a color.  You're already doing that.  2) Don't let that be the only wrought iron.  Maybe put up a piece of wrought iron artwork in the living room so it has something else to go with.  And/or, you could put up something like a hanging wrought iron pot rack in the kitchen or add a wrought iron etagere or end table. If it isn't a single different piece, it will look more cohesive.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the design of your house and the proximity of the fixtures. If the overall character of the house is similar, you may want to keep everything similar. However, we often "mix-it-up" if different areas are "different ".  Especially, if the "different" area has an unusual ceiling: (I.e.: different shape, height, color, use, etc.)

If the fixture can't be seen from another fixture, I doubt anyone will notice.